# Game strategy- choose between two urns and two colors

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I found the following game in a (non-math) book:

> We have two urns $A$ and $B$. $A$ contains black and red balls of equal amount. Whereas the ratio, $\frac{r}{s}$, of black and red balls of urn $B$ is unknown. You are free to choose an urn and then a color. Next the moderator draws a ball from the chosen urn. If it matches your color you win if not you loose.
>
> Which urn should you choose?

---

I doubt that we can solve this game/find an optimal strategy without any further information.

If we choose urn $A$ then the probability to win, $P(A)$, can be found by law of total probability, i.e.
\begin{align*}
&P(A)=P(moderator~red\mid player~red)P(player~red)+P(moderator~black\mid player~black)P(player~black)\\
&=0.5\cdot P(player~red)+0.5\cdot P(player~black)=(P(player~red)+P(player~black))\cdot0.5=0.5
\end{align*}
If we choose urn $B$ and apply law of total probability, then
\begin{align*}
&P(B)=P(moderator~red\mid player~red)P(player~red)+P(moderator~black\mid player~black)P(player~black)\\
&=\frac{r}{r+s}\cdot P(player~red)+\frac{s}{r+s}\cdot P(player~black)=?
\end{align*}

---

However, the author states that it doesn't matter which urn we choose.

I suppose that he assumes that if the player chooses urn $B$ he decides with equal probability between both colors. This indeed yields $P(A)=P(B)=0.5$.

But why should we assume this? Or is there another reason or argument why both strategies should yield the same winning probability?

Comment: While B's contents are unknown, I think the additional assumption here is that there is no _a-priori_ reason to believe urn B contains more balls of a certain color.  OTOH if you know the moderator chooses what balls go into B and also likes the color red, you might want to choose B and red.  BTW $P(player\ \  red)$ is not a real probability unless you are using a probabilistic strategy.

Comment: @antkam Well this is embarrassing.  I misinterpreted the problem and posted a bad answer.  Then, I misinterpreted the problem **again**, and posted another bad answer.  I bow to destiny; it not my destiny to give a good answer to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implicit in the problem statement is the assumption that the two colors red and black are on equal footing. The description is certainly invariant under the switching of the words "red" and "black" and informal notions of probability tends to consider such symmetries to preserve probabilities. Slightly more formally, consider a second participant in the experiment with the same role as you and who uses exactly the same strategy as you except switches the two colors. Given the information in the problem and an Occam's razor point of view, you would not expect them to perform better or worse than you. From this it is not hard to see that if there is a well defined probability of success with the mystery urn it has to be $1/2$.

On the other hand, consider a situation where you don't know how many red balls there are in urn $B$, but you do know that it has a million more black balls. Then the ratio $r/s$ is still *unknown* but it's clearly better to pick urn $B$ and black.

In other words, a reasonable restriction on the prior distribution of $r/s$ is that it should have all the symmetries that the problem description does. In this case that implies that the probability of success given urn $B$ is also $1/2$. In the absence of such a restriction, the choice of urn can matter.

Answer (score 0):

Let $R_B=\frac{r}{b}$ be the ratio of red balls to black balls in urn B. It depends on the distribution of $ X=\frac{r}{r+b}$. Let's assume that $X=\frac{r}{r+b}= \frac{R_B}{1+R_B}$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$.

After we choose an urn, if we  choose red with probability $p$ and black color with probability $1-p$, then

$$P(w|A) = P(w|A,r)P(r|A) + P(w|A,b)P(b|A) = \frac 12 p + \frac 12 (1-p) = \frac 12.$$

And for urn B we have,

$P(w|B) = P(w|B,r)P(r|B) + P(w|B,b)P(b|B)  = p\,P(w|B,r) + (1-p)\,P(w|B,b).$

Using the law of total probability and since $f_{X}(x)=1$ for urn B:

$P(w|B,r) = \int_{0}^{1} P(w|B,r, X=x) f_X(x)\,dx = \int_{0}^{1} P(w|B,r,X=x)\,  dx = \int_{0}^{1} x\,  dx = \frac 12.$

$P(w|B,b) = \int_{0}^{1} P(w|B,b, X=x) f_X(x)\,dx = \int_{0}^{1} P(w|B,b,X=x)\,  dx = \int_{0}^{1} 1-x \, dx = \frac 12.$

so,
$$P(w|B) = p\,\frac 12 +(1-p) \frac 12= \frac 12.$$

It seems it doesn't depend on $p$, i.e., if $X=\frac{r}{r+b}$ is uniformly distributed then both probabilities are the same and it doesn't matter which urn to choose. It only depends on the distribution of $X=\frac{r}{r+b}$.

**UPDATED:**

**Case 2:** Again let $f_X(x)$ be density distribution of $X=\frac{r}{r+b}$, but this time it is unknown. Then,

$P(w|B,r) = \int_{0}^{1} P(w|B,r, X=x) f_X(x)\,dx = \int_{0}^{1} x\,f_X(x)\,  dx $
$P(w|B,b) = \int_{0}^{1} P(w|B,b, X=x) f_X(x)\,dx = \int_{0}^{1} (1-x)\,f_X(x)\,  dx = 1 - \int_{0}^{1} x\,f_X(x)\,  dx = 1 - P(w|B,r).$

Now if $p=\frac 12$, (recall that $p$ is the probability of choosing the red color) then
$$P(w|B) = \frac 12 P(w|B,r) + \frac 12 (1-P(w|B,r)) = \frac 12. $$
which again shows it doesn't matter which urn to choose if $p=\frac 12$ but $X=\frac{r}{r+b}$ can have any distribution.

Comment: I dont think it is reasonable to think that $\frac{r}{r+b}$, which in practice is "almost surely" (pun intended) a small rational number, is $\sim U[0, 1]$.  :)   Really, the argument can be boiled down to: if we assume symmetry of the distribution of $\frac{r}{r+b}$ around $1/2$, then the symmetry argument is entirely sufficient to show which color you choose doesn't matter -- no need for any integrals.  And if we don't assume symmetry, then there is no reason think why the choice of color would not matter.

Comment: Obviously. It only depends on the distribution of the ratio. I didn’t say that r/(r+b) is symmetric or around 1/2. Please read the answer more carefully.

Comment: My point is: why assume $X \sim U[0,1]$ (which you call "reasonable") and go through the trouble of doing integrals, when you can draw the same conclusion using the much weaker assumption that $X$ is symmetric about $1/2$?  $U[0,1]$ is just one example of such a symmetric distribution.

Comment: Look at that the update for a general distribution of $f_X(x)$ for the ratio $X=\frac{r}{r+b}$ but $p=\frac 12$.  Remember that $X$ can have any distribution but as long as we choose red color or black color with  the same probability (we are not biased toward one color) we get the same probability of winning for each urn. @Philipp has also mentioned this but I think the calculations should be more accurate.

Comment: of _course_ if you choose red with prob $1/2$ (i.e. you employ a probabilistic strategy) then your winning chance is $1/2$.  but if i know $X$, and i know it favors red, then my $P(red) = 1$ (deterministic strategy) for sure!  after all, that's the point of the game -- to choose an urn and a color (both choices can be deterministic or probabilistic).

Comment: the OP's question is "why does it not matter which urn i pick?"  here are some answers. (1) "win prob = $1/2$ if you pick the color randomly" <-- IMHO this is an uninteresting answer because why are you restricted to picking the color randomly?  the question never said that.  (2) "win prob = $1/2$ if you 'reasonably' assume $X$ is symmetric about $1/2$ (with $U[0,1]$ being an example).  in this case it doesnt matter which (urn, color) combo you pick, whether deterministically or probabilistically."  that's my answer, and also a generalized version of your original answer.